# design pattern for concurrent task execution with constraints

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns, concurrency, scheduled-tasks

I have 3 classes of task (I, D, U) which come in on a queue, tasks of the same class must be processed in order.  I want tasks to run as concurrently as possible; however there are some constraints:

- U and D cannot run concurrently
- U and I cannot run concurrently
- I(n) requires U(n) has completed

**Q:** What design pattern(s) would fit this class of problem?

I have two approaches I am considering:

***Approach 1:***
Use 1 Thread per task, each with its own queue.  Each thread has a synchronized start phase where it checks start conditions, then runs, then a synchronized stop phase.  It is easy to see that this will provide good concurrency but I am unsure if it correctly implements my constraints and doesnt deadlock.

```
D_Thread { ...
 while (task = D_Queue.take()) {
  synchronized (State) {   // start phase
   waitForU();
   State.setRunning(D, true);
  }
  run(task);  // run phase
  synchronized (State) {   // stop phase
    State.setRunning(D, false) 
  }
 }
}
```

***Approach 2:*** Alternatively, a single dispatch thread manages execution state, and schedules tasks in a ThreadPool, waiting if necessary for currently scheduled tasks to complete.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on third constraint? Do I and U come in pairs and each I requires its paired U, or there are no such pairs but merely the number of completed I's can not be greater than the numbers of completed U's? Or something else?

Comment: 2) What is the time cost for each class of tasks? Do they take approximately the same time to complete?

Comment: A bit of both.  U(n) is kind of a cache flush, it implies U(n-1) U(n-2) ... and so on; so its possible to process several at once.  Each operation has a position associated with it; so D(k) actually creates a requirement for U(k).  They were meant as examples; I'm not asking people to fully solve this problem; just recommend some design patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Objective-C Foundation framework includes classes `NSOperationQueue` and `NSOperation` that satisfy some of these requirements. `NSOperationQueue` represents a queue of `NSOperation`s. The queue runs a configurable maximum number of operations concurrently. Operations have a priority and a set of dependencies; all of the operations that an operation depends on must be completed before the queue will start running the operation. The operations are scheduled to run on a dynamically-sized pool of threads.

What you need requires a somewhat smarter version of `NSOperationQueue` that applies the constraints you have expressed, but `NSOperationQueue` and company provide an example of how roughly your problem has been solved in a production framework that resembles your second suggested solution of a dispatch thread running tasks on a thread pool.

Comment: It looks like NSOperationQueue uses a directed acyclic graph of dependencies and a bounded thread pool to schedule everything which is not pending another result.

Comment: I couldn't see a way to express my constraints in terms of forward dependencies.

Comment: I'll take it, this does not solve the problem but it is what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this turns out to be more simple than it seemed: a mutex is mainly all that is needed:

```
IThread(int k) {
 synchronized (u_mutex) {
  if (previousUSet.contains(k))) U(k);
 }
 I(k);
}

DThread(int k) {
 synchronized (u_mutex) {
  D(k);
  previousUSet.add(k);
 }
}
```